# Different alert thresholds depending on the current time

Tags: datadog

I was wondering if I can somehow use different thresholds depending on the current time. For example, if I lose traffic on my website for 10 minutes while I'm on my working hours, I'd like to get notified to fix it quickly.

But if I lose traffic for only 10 mins at night, I feel like sometimes it's not worth to wake up.

I've been trying to search for a way of doing something like that but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 3):

I believe a common solution to this sort of use-case is to just set up 2 monitors with the different thresholds and use [scheduled downtimes](https://docs.datadoghq.com/monitors/downtimes/?tab=bymonitorname) to silence them from alerting during the times you don't want them to.

Other approaches exist, but this one's pretty simple, doesn't take much work.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a daily cron job / scheduled AWS Lambda / etc to mute the monitor using the [Datadog API](https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/v1/monitors/#mute-a-monitor). You need the monitor id, the POSIX timestamp of when to unmute the monitor (ie 12 hours from now), and your client API and client app keys from your [account settings](https://app.datadoghq.com/account/settings#api).

```
curl -X POST https://api.datadoghq.com/api/v1/monitor/${monitor_id}/mute?end=${timestamp} \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "DD-API-KEY: ${DD_CLIENT_API_KEY}" \
  -H "DD-APPLICATION-KEY: ${DD_CLIENT_APP_KEY}"
```

You may want also want a backup monitor with a longer alert timeframe (for example, alert if there is no traffic in 6 hours).

Comment: While this solution should work, it adds even more components that can break, feels a bit tedious to set up and would require a non negligible amount of maintenance. 
Put in another way, if you had a 100+ monitors with this use case, this clearly wouldn't be an option.